# Web Application for mobile

Tags: javascript, ios5, sencha-touch-2

I just learned Sencha Touch 2 framework, I want to connect from Sencha to database and it can be Select, insert, update, delete (SQL)

any simple code and idea to learn it?

thanks

Comment: can't you use phone gap for all the database purposes?????

Comment: if yes ,then read this document http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 LocalStorage is the way for offline data.

Please read the Sencha Documentation.

Start reading something about the data package: [SenchaDataPackage](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/data)

**EDIT**
You can refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007805/i-want-an-sample-sencha-touch-application-that-deals-with-database) question as well.

Hope it helps.