# How to populate a list in Sencha Touch 2 with values from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Following this [tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app) (specifically the part about the blog), I was able to create a list that displays information from JSON. My goal is to do something similar except with values from a MySQL table. Specifically, I would like to create a list of "titles" concatenated with the "numberOfPages" from a table called "Books." How can I go about doing so? My initial thought was to get JSON from the database and implement the list as mentioned in the tutorial, but I have no idea how to do that. Do I have the right idea, or is there a more preferable way to do what I need in Sencha Touch 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll will have to use php to connect to the database and convert the results you get from your MySQL database to JSON so Sencha Touch can use it. This post should help you out:

[I want an sample sencha touch application that deals with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007805/i-want-an-sample-sencha-touch-application-that-deals-with-database)